# numpy array, slicing 4d array (tensor)

Tags: numpy, scipy

I want to access a 4d numpy.ndarray( don't know exactly how and if it differs from a tensor). 
i want the  3d array (cube when) the 4th dimension has the index 1 for example.

i tried something like

```
 array[:][:][:][1]
```

but no avail

Answer (score 2):

Should just be:

```
array[:, :, :, 1]
```